How to use with on a protected member extension in Kotlin?
I stumbled upon this when trying to create a custom androidx.compose.ui.graphics.painter.Painter for my jetpack compose application. I'd like to create a decorator like:
class MyPainter(private val delegate: Painter) : Painter() {

    override fun DrawScope.onDraw() {
        with(delegate) { // warning: "redundant 'with' call"
            onDraw()
        }
        // draw other stuff
    }

    override val intrinsicSize: Size get() = delegate.intrinsicSize

}

But this just calls MyPainter#onDraw instead of the extension method from the decorator.
After a bit of experimentation, I created an example base class:
abstract class StringPrinter {
    abstract fun String.getPrinted()
    fun print(value: String) = value.getPrinted()
}

Example implementation:
class StringConsolePrinter : StringPrinter() {
    override fun String.getPrinted() {
        println(this)
    }
}

and finally an example decorator:
class StringBackwardsPrinter(private val delegate: StringPrinter) : StringPrinter() {
    override fun String.getPrinted() {
        with(delegate) {
            reversed().getPrinted()
        }
    }
}

This works fine, and
StringBackwardsPrinter(StringConsolePrinter()).print("test")

prints "tset" as expected. However, as soon as I make getPrinted method protected, the delegate extension method is no longer called:
abstract class StringPrinter {
    protected abstract fun String.getPrinted() // no longer works
    fun print(value: String) = value.getPrinted()
}

Why does that happen? Is there some way to work around this?
(Kotlin version 1.9.21)

It doesn't have to do anything with the fact that they are extensions, it's how encapsulation of protected functions works. If you convert your extension to "normal" function and call it directly instead of scoped with() you can see the error.

ahhhhh so protected method of one subclass cannot be called from another subclass… huh, didn't realize that, thanks!

This has nothing to do with extension methods. It's just that a protected method of one subclass cannot be used within another subclass. Example:
abstract class ProtectedExample {
    protected abstract fun test()
}

Then:
class ProtectedExampleDecorator(private val delegate: ProtectedExample) : ProtectedExample() {
    override fun test() {
        delegate.test() // Cannot access 'test': it is protected in 'ProtectedExample'
    }
}

